# Submitting build to iTunes Connect but not showing

Tags: ios, phonegap

i created the build in phonegap and uploading the IOS build through [app uploader](http://www.applicationloader.net/) on itunes connect its uploading successfully but its not showing in appname->activity->all builds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some issue in your build. Apple developer admin/agent must have received an email stating the issue.

Comment: yes i received email earlier but when i upload the correct build it didn't showed there.

Comment: Every time you upload the build with issue, you'll receive an email stating that issue and the build will not be shown in the itunes connect.

Comment: but there is not any error inmy build and I didn't receive any email and still not showing up in itunes connect

Comment: I did not get email. I have uploaded 4 build version but same issue.